# Unable to unbind the window beforeunload event in Jquery

Tags: bind, jquery, unbind

I have a page where the user can drag and drop objects and save them as an image.When a user navigates away from the page, the event ***beforeunload*** is fired. Now, this happens every time. What i want to do is, unbind the event if the user has saved his work, so that the message may not pop up again.To do this i have used the
***unbind*** method in ***jQuery***. But, it does not seem to work. Below is the code for binding and unbinding the events.

```
var notSaved = function()
{
   return 'You have not yet saved your work.Do you want to continue? Doing so, may cause loss of your work' ;
}
$(window).bind('beforeunload', notSaved);
```

After save method has been called,

```
$(window).unbind('beforeunload', notSaved);
```

What am i doing wrong here?
**Also, the save method is actually an Ajax call.**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`beforeunload` doesn't work reliably this way, as far as binding goes.  You should assign it natively:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return 'You have not yet saved your work.Do you want to continue? Doing so, may cause loss of your work' ;
}
```

And in your save method:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Comment: Thank you so much...that saved the day for me :)

Comment: This won't work in IE, what you want is `window.onbeforeunload = undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
const windowReloadBind = function(message) {
    window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
        //--- Your logic
        return 'your output';
    }
};

const windowReloadUnBind = function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      return null;
    };
};
```